# Solving: "If x double, y changes by what?" using differentiation.

Tags: calculus, word-problem

I recently saw this word problem:

Given $$y = \frac12x^2$$
if $x$ doubles, $y$ changes by what?

Someone solved it using basic numbers and substitution. The answer is $4$.
However, my gut feeling when I see the question is to differentiate it, obtaining:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x$$

i.e. the slope of the parabola at point $x$ is $x$ itself, which leads me nowhere near the answer. Is there a way to go from $\frac{dy}{dx} = x$ to the answer? Is there a way to solve this using Calculus? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would you want to use calculus? $x$ does not change infinitesimally!

Comment: @YiFan is it bad to find new ways to solve a problem?

Comment: the approach has to actually work in order to be considered a new solution.

Comment: You could integrate $x$ from $x_0$ to $2x_0$, add the result to $\frac12x_0^2,$ and then take the ratio of the result to $\frac12x_0^2$ if you really want to do everything the hard way.

Comment: You shouldn't expect this to work, because the derivative only gives you "local" information, while multiplying by $x$ by $2$ takes you way out of $x's$ "neighborhood."

Comment: thanks, these are helpful

Comment: @YiFan so the approach has to actually work before you start considering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculus wont work because $dy$ and $dx$ are infinitesimally small. The change in x or ${\Delta x}$ in the question is very large and is comparable to the values to x.

The way to solve this would be-
$$y={1\over 2}x^2$$
$$y'={1\over 2}(2x)^2 = {4\times {1\over 2}x^2} = 4y$$

Hence when x is doubled, y will be quadrupled.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to make it clear that $y'$ here just denotes the new value of $y$, not $dy/dx$. This quite confused me on first glance.

Comment: Agreed. Additionally, $y$ could be written as $f(x)$ and $y'$ as $f(2x)$. I also find David K's comment above useful. Essentially the calculus method to find the ratio between 1) the integral of $x_0$ to $x_2$ and 2) the integral of $x_0$ to $x_1$. My original sin was when asked a question about distance and given speed, I tried to find the acceleration.